# Does java has helper classes for setting printer options

Tags: java, printing

Through java program I will generate a file which has to be printed later, can we change printer settings using java program I went through PrinterJob were basic options like resizing and formatting are available but my requirement is such I need to render background images too as in printing bond papers where the background will change for different documents.

Any help will be much appreciated.